# Inserting data to MySQL from file (csv, sql) in PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

My situation is as follows. I have a remote database, which i can only access via ssh-tunnel. I promptly configured it as a `Data Source` in `PHPStorm` and everything works fine. However, i often need to operate moderately large tables (several millions of records), so simply copy-pasting `INSERT` statements to add data doesn't work.

I tried googling it, search `PhpStorm Help`, but there is no info at all. Perhaps, some plugin exists for such task, or is there another way of inserting data from files via `PHPStorm`?

Comment: PhpStorm (Database support plugin, to be precise) is the wrong tool for operating such large number of records (import/export/etc) -- its main purpose is to help you writing the code (sql queries/table structure etc). You better use more appropriate soft/solutions for that. Since you are accessing it via SSH, you could/should use your DB native command line tools for such operations (bulk insert/sql dump).

Comment: Using command line is the way i'm doing it right now, so it's more question of convenience than anything else, but i was still wondering if it is possible with PHPStorm.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the sql file to your project files, right-click this file in the Project view and select "Run {filename}" You will then be asked to select the right database, on which the sql will execute.

Comment: as of now (July 2020) you don't need to put the sql file into your project. I had the issue that the dump was on an external hard drive and I couldn't copy it to my local mashine. you can just right click the DB in the database tab of PhpStorm and click ´Run SQL Script...´ from the context menu. select your dump to insert it

Answer (score 7):

**Step by step guide to execute Mysql Script from `PhpStrom` or any Jet Brain's intelligence IDE**

1.Put your MySQL script file in current project directory.

2.Right click and select option `Run_{fileName.sql}` from Context menu (Tip: you can also select multiple files if you want.)

[image]

3.Select appropriate Schema/database name in `Target data source/Schema`

[image]

4.click on Run button. After that execution of operations will going to start.

Answer (score 3):

searching a solution for a similar issue I found a way to import data to mysql phpstorm data resource from the sql console typing this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/your_csv_file.csv' 
INTO TABLE your_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(column1, column2, column3, ...);
```

Maybe could be useful for you.